The task XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted or out of range
How can I find which value is incorrectly formatted or out of range?
Below is just an example of an error showing when running: Get-ScheduledTask | Format-Table TaskName. I would like to find a general solution for solving errors when executing this last statement.
PS D:\> get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Office ClickToRun Service Monitor"
get-ScheduledTask : The task XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted or out of range.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Office ClickToRun Service Monitor"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...T_ScheduledTask) [Get-ScheduledTask]
   , CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041318,Get-ScheduledTask

The current contents of that file ("C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Office\Office ClickToRun Service Monitor") are:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2005-10-11T13:21:17-08:00</Date>
    <Author>Microsoft Office</Author>
    <Description>This task monitors the state of your Microsoft Office ClickToRunSvc and sends crash and error logs to Microsoft.</Description>
    <URI>\Microsoft\Office\Office ClickToRun Service Monitor</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2010-12-16T04:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <RandomDelay>PT6H</RandomDelay>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>P1D</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT30M</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\ClientX64\OfficeC2RClient.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>/WatchService</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>

P.S. I validated this XML, using Notepad++ with the XML Tools plugin, which claimed it to be valid.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

More info would help. What created that task? Installation of MS Office? If so, what version?  On what version of Windows? Did this issue result from attempting to install a version of MS Office on a version of Windows incompatible with it?

I am on Windows 11. on a system that was upgrade from Windows 10.  Impossible to tell which Microsoft Office version where installed, but Office 15 seems to be one of them

Impossible to tell the Office version? Do you have the computer in front of you or are you able to remote into it? What effort did you make to determine the Office version? You may have components of various versions of Office, but there should be only 1 version of the full Office product, and this should be pretty clear in the various places the Office install is recorded, and in the applications themselves.

@music2myear:  But the question is not about office. The line about Office it throwing an error when executing powershell get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Office ClickToRun Service Monitor".  The error has not relationship with Office, because there are other tasks with the same error.

But when you really want to know it's Office 2013. (But, again, this is unrelated to the question!)
